# shortcut to select all objects in collection in outliner does not work

Tags: shortcut, outliner

I have set a shortcut to select objects in outliner like this:

[image]

If i select the collection and tap my shortcut key...nothing happens.

If i select the collection and tap the menu point with the assigned shortcut key - works.

Is it a bug? Does anybody know a workaround for this? Or am i doing this wrong?

Comment: This operation is context sensitive : It will only work if your mouse is hovering over an outliner editor.

Comment: @Chris I don't even have the option to assign shortcut for such operator https://imgur.com/UD95S6W How did you assign it? :) BTW is it a time-saver since you have to select Collection first?

Comment: It saves 2 clicks so….YES and because I use trackpad - my steering isn’t that exact

Comment: @vklidu: i right clicked in the outline on that menu entry ;)

Comment: @Gorgious: even than...it is not working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not working because <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> is already assigned to *Toggle Selected*

[image]

Comment: OMG.....thank you!! Cannot believe i didn't check that....‍♂️